# Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment

Tags: javascript

lo que quiero hacer es que cuando le de a un boton cambie la imagen de un div pero no se cual es el algoritmo para eso , osea , tomar el elemento DIV de html y alterar el STYLE "background-image".

```
<style>
    .camara {
        border: 1px solid #ccc;
        background-image: url("index2.jpg");
        background-position: center;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: cover;
        width: 100%;
        height: 70%;
    };
</style>
```

aparte que los atributos de el div estan en el tag STYLE y no se si tengo que tomar ese tag o el div en fin necesito saber si hay un algorimo para hacerlo.

bien , este es el error que me aparce cuando uso el algorimo

```
div.style.background-image = (alemania);
```

"alemania" es la variable donde guarde la imagen pero me da un error: "Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment"

no se exactamente a lo que refiere con Lado izquierdo no valido en la asignación.

Comment: y que sabes hacer en javascript??? conoces jquery???

Comment: ehh no estoy aprendiendo y esto es parte de un proyecto personal

Comment: ya te deje la respuesta incluye el algoritmo y un ejemplo en código, ten en cuenta que este sitio no te darán ayuda y es mal visto si no has realizado un mínimo esfuerzo en investigar como se hace cada cosa.

Comment: lo e investigado pero no e encontrado nada al respecto

Comment: ok entiendo muchas gracias al parecer lo escribi mal

Comment: significa que el codigo tiene error de sintaxis y la asignacion que estas haciendo es invalida, yo te deje en mi respuesta un ejemplo del codigo ya lo revisaste?

Answer (score 0):

El algoritmo en javascript en teoría es el siguiente:

1. Validar si se cargo el DOM (HTML y recursos) de la pagina
2. Establecer un constructor de evento apuntando al Boton para el evento click
3. guardar el nodo de la imagen en una variable.
4. guardar la `url` de la nueva imagen en una variable.
5. ejecutar el comando `document.body.style.backgroundImage` = (variable nueva imagen).

y un ejemplo de código lo encuentras en esta dirección:

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_style_backgroundimage

Comment: hmm , creo que tendre que reformular la pregunta por que me da un error

Comment: no asi no se hace eso es otra pregunta tenias que abrir otra publicacion... y colocar el codigo de lo que hiciste...

Comment: eh no fui yo fue otra persona

Comment: segun lo que leo de tu post alemania debe ser una URL, lo es??? haste un console.log(alemania) y valida que contiene.